# How to make Lenovo Thinkpad switch for AP with best reception?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, thinkpad, roaming-profiles

I recently changed the my network so that the 4 devices (1 router, 3AP's) is running on one SSID and different channels (instead of 4 different SSID's on same channel). I had some problems with testing if roaming was now working, because for some reason my ThinkPad don't want to roam. I now know that the roaming is in fact working because I have tested it with other Windows and Mac computers. But my Lenovo, for some reason, prefers to log onto an AP/router with bad reception, although I might be just next to another AP. In this moment it uses an AP with 25% signal, although there is one with 100% with same SSID. For some reason it is not scanning for a stronger signal with the same SSID as it is currently using.
My pc is a LENOVO ThinkPad Edge 15" 13.3 i3-380UM W7HP64 running windows 7.
The Adapter is 1x1 11b/g/n Wireless LAN PCI Express Half Mini Card Adapter for Windows 7 running driverversion 1005.15.223.2011 (Realtek Semiconductor Corp)
The other windows pc (which is roaming) is also running windows 7 - wifi adapter: qualcomm atheros AR9285 802.11b/g/n WiFi adapter driver 10.0.0.67.
I just tried to change roaming sensitivity level from low to high but with out any luck.

Comment: Without knowing anything about it, I doubt that being a Thinkpad is the problem. Could you add information on what wifi device is used (maybe driver version as well?). What about the other Windows devices. Are they also running Windows 7? What wifi cards do they use?

Comment: I just updated the post with more info